# AntlrWorks error: antlr4

Tags: java, debugging, error-handling, antlr3, antlrworks

So I'm pretty new to antlr, and I'm trying to write a program that will look for keywords and then make a tree of the numbers/words after, ending at \n and excluding the '|' symbol.

I'm getting several error, and am not sure about my grammar in general:
Cannot display rule "X" because start state not found

any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Don't use v3, it's quite old and I haven't seen anyone actively answer questions about it in a while. Go with ANTLR v4 and pick one of the editors or tools from this page: http://www.antlr.org/tools.html

Comment: does ANTLRWorks not work with antlr4?  I downloaded antlr4.  Antlrworks was recommended for running it.

Comment: not the version you're using now (ANTLRWorks2 works with ANTLR v4). ANTLRWorks 1 only handles v3 grammars. ANTLRWorks 1 has the v3 libraries included, so you're really not using v4. You may have downloaded v4, but you sure aren't using it in the grammar you posted. Check the link I posted earlier.

Comment: What is the `public line+;` line supposed to mean? I don't think that is valid grammar. Also, it is much better to include the code as text not as an image in your question.